# Apex chart change color of series.name

Tags: javascript, json, apexcharts

I want to change the colors of the text associated with series.name

in the attached pic (Assembly, metal shop, etc.)

I tried changing x-axis.labels.style.color but it didn't affect series.name also I have tried to labels.style.color to the series but it doesn't work also

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.